# HTML <track> element shows cues in console but also length = 0 and they cannot be accessed by indexing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a page with a video player in which I'm trying to show vtt captions and get information from the cues in the `<track>` element.

Here's what's relevant for the player in HTML:

```
<div class="video">
  <video id="vid">
    <source src="Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track kind="subtitles" src="Captions.vtt" srclang="en">
  </video>
</div>
```

I had something like this in my JavaScript first, just to see what I was getting before manipulating anything in code.

```
var trackObject = $('track')[0].track;
trackObject.mode = 'showing';

console.log('Track cues:');
console.log(trackObject.cues);
console.log(trackObject.cues[0]);
```

The change to the `mode` attribute is done there because, if I set `default` to the `<track>` element in HTML, then the video doesn't appear in many browsers. Still don't know why.

What this prints to the console is the following:

[image]

However, when I expand the `TextTrackCueList`, I do see the cues:

[image]

[image]

This has only made sense to me if I assume that the cues have loaded into the element, but the `length` attribute hasn't been updated. But I still don't know what's that length I'm seeing at the end of the list, which shows the actual number of cues.

I haven't found any kind of load event on the text track, so this is what I did to make sure I can get the cues:

```
var trackObject = $('track')[0].track;
trackObject.mode = 'showing';

var waitForCues = setInterval(function() {
  if (trackObject.cues.length > 0) {
    var cueList = getTracks(trackObject)
    // ...Do some processing with the cues...
    clearInterval(waitForCues);
  }

}, 40);
```

Why does this happen with the `length` attribute of the track element? How can I get rid of that waiting for the length to be greater than 0?

Comment: Small note on using JS: use `<script src="myscript.js" async defer></script>` in your head, and now you don't need the whole "$.ready` construct anymore. That was necessary back in the days before [the defer attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) existed but that's _quite_ a long time ago: even IE has supported it for over a decade now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Great. Now, reading the doc, I realized I didn't even need the `defer` attr, because this script is of type `module`. Changed it and it still works. Not completely necessary, but edited the code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an HTMLMediaElement, the `<track>` element supports the same global `load` and `error` events that any other HTMLElement does, so you can listen for those to determine whether your VTT is ready for business or not.

```js
mytrack.addEventListener(`load`, evt => {
  console.log(`good to go`);
  const { track } = mytrack;
  // force this track to become active so we can get the cues:
  track.mode = "showing";
  const { cues } = track;
  console.log(`${cues.length} cues found`);
});

mytrack.addEventListener(`error`, evt => {
  console.log(`yeah that's a problem`);
});
```

```html
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track
           id="mytrack"
           kind="captions"
           src="data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,WEBVTT%0A%0A00%3A00%3A00.500%20--%3E%2000%3A00%3A02.000%0AThe%20Web%20is%20always%20changing%0A%0A00%3A00%3A02.500%20--%3E%2000%3A00%3A04.300%0Aand%20the%20way%20we%20access%20it%20is%20changing"
           srclang="en"
           label="English"
           default="default">
    >
  </video>
```

Comment: Great. I could use this to get rid of the `setInterval()` to check when the cues are actually there. Do you know why it shoes the cues there in the console when expanded but the length is `0` and no element can be accessed? I don't think I can assume it's because the element is not ready, because the cues are there.

Comment: What's `trackObject`'s class? Because I don't see anything with a `cues` property, although text tracks do have `activeCues`.

Comment: `trackObject` is the name I gave to the `TextTrack` you get when you do `$('track')[0].track` in my case with the HTML code I showed. I didn't show a screenshot in the question, but [here it is](https://imgur.com/a/ONuysBo).

Comment: I've updated the code in this asnwer, but I don't see that happening. Setting the track mode to `showing` after it has loaded shows the cues list being populated. You're probably going to have to edit your post to link to a true [mcve] on repl.it or glitch or something with code that others can "remix" into a working state.

Comment: The thing is that accessing the cues after they load solves that problem. When you try to access the cues or the track's length outside of that event handler, right when the page loads, do they still show? Is the length still `2`? I accepted your answer because it's a way to get rid of the `setInterval()` and it makes sense to wait for the cues to load. However, I still have no idea why the `length` behaves the way I showed in the two images in the question. I'm honestly thinking about what to add to the code, but it's really all what's needed to reproduce it.

Comment: Note that my code does the same as yours, but only "after the track loaded in". Honestly, the docs leave a lot to be desired here, so this might just be the best we're going to get, short of asking this question on the chromium and/or bugzilla trackers, or possibly even the TC39 webapis issue tracker.